# Pretty printing in Haskell: Break outer groups when printing nested tuples

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I want to pretty print an AST using Haskell and (currently) [wl-pprint-annotated](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated) (willing to switch to a different library).

How can I make the renderer prefer breaking the [softlines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated-0.1.0.1/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-Annotated-WL.html#v:-60--47--62-) of the outer group over the softlines of the inner group?

### Minimal Example

Take for example the tuple `((1234, 5678), (abcd, efgh))`.

The output I want:

```
// line width: 10
(
  (
    1234,
    5678
  ),
  (
    abcd,
    efgh
  )
)

// line width: 16
(
  (1234, 5678),
  (abcd, efgh)
)

// line width: 32
((1234, 5678), (abcd, efgh))
```

The output I get:

```
// line width: 10
((1234,
    5678),
  (abcd,
    efgh))

// line width: 16
((1234, 5678), (
    abcd, efgh))

// line width: 32
((1234, 5678), (abcd, efgh))
```

Code:

```
module Main where
import qualified Prelude
import Prelude hiding((<>))

import Text.PrettyPrint.Annotated.WL 

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ pp 10
  putStrLn $ pp 16
  putStrLn $ pp 32

pp w = "// line width: " ++ show w ++ "\n" ++
       display (renderPretty 1.0 w doc) ++ "\n"

doc = pair (pair (text "1234") (text "5678"))
           (pair (text "abcd") (text "efgh"))

pair x y = group (nest 2 (lparen <//> x <> comma </> y) <//> rparen)
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works or how robust it is but it seems to produce output you want on your examples. `pair x y = group (nest 2 (lparen <##> x <> comma <#> y) <##> rparen)`

Comment: @ekimboran That's awesome! It worked not only for my minimum example but also in the teststuite with more elaborated cases. Now that I've reread the documentation it describes the efect I wanted in a way that confused me while scanning over it.

Comment: @ekimboran Do you want to create an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pair x y = group (nest 2 (lparen <##> x <> comma <#> y) <##> rparen)
```

Answer (score 1):

As ekim found out, I've mixed up `</>` with `<#>`

I found the documentation to be confusing, so let me clear it up a little.

First of all the operators `</>` and `<#>` are just sugar for [`line`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated-0.1.0.1/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-Annotated-WL.html#v:line) and [`softline`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated-0.1.0.1/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-Annotated-WL.html#v:softline).
See [definitions](https://github.com/minad/wl-pprint-annotated/blob/01846cc4f14c51b1830274a37d9027955a398dfc/src/Text/PrettyPrint/Annotated/WL.hs#L349-L370):

```
x </> y = x <> softline <> y
x <#> y = x <> line <> y
```

My problem was that I was using `softline` when what I wanted was `line`.

##### Commonalities between `line` and `softline`

Both are printed as space when the whole line fits the page. Both are replaced with a line break when the line does not fit the page.

##### Difference between `line` and `softline`

When a group foes not fit the page, *all* [line](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated-0.1.0.1/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-Annotated-WL.html#v:line)s of the *whole* group are replaced with line breaks. That's the behavior I've wanted.

When the line does not fit the page, *only* the last [softline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated-0.1.0.1/docs/Text-PrettyPrint-Annotated-WL.html#v:softline) still fitting the page is replaced.
Not the whole group.
It's like the word wrapping in our text editors: Just breaking after the last word that fits to the page.

For example

```
doc = paragraph p1
paragraph = foldr (</>) mempty . map text . words
p1 = "I want to pretty print an AST using Haskell and (currently) wl-pprint-annotated (willing to switch to a different library)."
```

is printed as

```
I want to pretty print an AST using Haskell and
(currently) wl-pprint-annotated (willing to
switch to a different library).
```